# Why does this use of Java Generics not compile?

Tags: java, generics

For the life of me I cannot understand why the compiler won't let me do the following...

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestMap {
   private final Map<Integer, ? extends Number> map = new HashMap<Integer, Number>();

   public void put(Integer key, Long item) {
      this.map.put(key, item);
   }
}
```

Why does line `this.map.put(key, item)` cause a compile error?

I know that I can change the declaration of map to use `Number` rather than `? extends Number` to make it work but it seems to me that what I am doing is perfectly legal, and I would prefer to not allow Number objects in the map. I am using Java 1.6.0_13.

Comment: Contrary to what you think, `? extends Number` will allow Number objects.  The `? extends X` bounded wildcard means "X or a subclass of X".

Comment: Incidentally, `Number` is a `<? extends Number>` so even if inserting into a wildcard list was possible, it wouldn't achieve what you want. The fact that `Number` is abstract will.

Comment: You could do ((Map<Integer, Number>) map).put(key, item); if yu are sure about the type.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that Number objects would be allowed in the map. It appears that I need to remove the wildcard and just use Number.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[You can't insert into collections that use wildcard types](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html). This is because, while a `List<Float>` can be passed to a method that accepts `List<? extends Number>`, it isn't safe to insert a `Long` into it. In your case, one might expect the compiler to know better as the definition of the collection is so visible, but it doesn't.

Comment: Explained here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: The compiler can't allow it because it can't take responsibility for where that map ends up being passed or used. Sure as a human we can eyeball the program and say it isn't used in any way that matters, but the compiler can only look at the put against the type declaration.

Comment: You can insert into collecitons that use wildcard types. You just have to do it correctly.  The PECS rule: Producer Extends Consumer Super, which means if you are getting from the collection, then use <? extends Number>, if you are putting objects into it, then use <? super Number>.  If you have List<? super Number>, you can insert a Long into it.  It allows you the flexibility to pass in List<Object> or List<Number>, etc.

Comment: @Chris Lacasse A great example of why Java has deviated from its roots of being easy to understand!

Comment: Joshua Bloch, who led the JSR that introduced generics, had stated that wildcards were a mistake:
http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=222021

Answer (score 7):

This is related to generics covariance.

When you declare,

```
Map<Integer, ? extends Number> map
```

you can't insert anything to the map because you can't guarantee that `? extends Number` is a `Long`, for instance.

Imagine this situation:

```
   Map<Integer, ? extends Number> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

   public void put(Integer key, Long item) {
      this.map.put(key, item);
   }
```

Here, `Integer != Long` and yet both obey `? extends Number`.

Answer (score 0):

Supplying the wildcard to a generic type effectively makes it read-only.